# How to retry hot observable?

Tags: system.reactive

Rx has great function Observable.Buffer. But there is a problem with it in real life.

Scenario: application sends a stream of events to a database. Inserting events one-by-one is expensive, so we need to batch it. I want to use Observable.Buffer for this. But inserting into DB has small probability of failure (deadlocks, timeouts, downtime, etc).

I can add some retry logic into batching function itself, but it would be against Rx idea of composablility. Observable.Retry does not cut it, because it will re-subscribe to "hot" source, which means that failed batch will be lost.

Are there functions, which I can compose to achieve desired effect, or do I need to implement my own extension? I would like something like this:

```
_inputBuffer = new BufferBlock<int>();
_inputBuffer.AsObservable().
    Buffer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), 1000).
    Do(batch => SqlSaveBatch(batch)).
    {Retry???}.
    Subscribe()
```

To make it perfect, I would like to be able to get control over situation when OnComplete is called, while retry buffer has incomplete batches, and be able to perform some actions (send error email, save data to local file system, etc.)

Answer (score 3):

When a save to database fails and needs to be retried, it's not really the stream or the events that are in error, it's a action taken against an event.

I would structure your code more like this:

```
IDisposable subscription =
    _inputBuffer.AsObservable().
    Buffer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), 1000).
    Subscribe(
        batch => SqlSaveBatchWithRetryLogic(batch),
        () => YourOnCompleteAction);
```

- You can provide the retry logic inside of `SqlSaveBatchWithRetryLogic()`
- Handle OnComplete of the events inside `YourOnCompleteAction()`
- You can elect to dispose the subscription from within `SqlSaveBatchWithRetryLogic()` if you fail to save a batch.
- This also removes the `Do` side effect.

I would be careful about this approach though - you need to watch the retry logic. You have no back-pressure (way to slow down the input). So if you have any kind of back-off/retry you are risking the queue backing up and filling memory. If you start seeing batches consistently at the  count limit, you are probably in trouble! You may want to implement a counter to monitor the outstanding items.

Comment: In perfect solution I would be able to reuse this retry logic. Otherwise, I'll have to come up with SqlSaveBatchWithRetryLogic, RabbitMQWithRetryLogic, MemcachedWithRetryLogic, etc.

Comment: You can put that abstraction in the handler though, can't you?

Comment: I cant see how "YourOnCompleteAction" can wait for SqlSaveBatchWithRetryLogic drainage of internal buffers. I mean I can see how to implement it, but it would involve some state variable shared between those two function, which would involve more code than I would like.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem you are driving at. As long as `SqlSaveBatchWithRetryLogic` only returns when it's completely done with a given buffer (which presumably is what you want) then Rx handles it because it guarantees not to make overlapping OnXXX calls to a given subscriber. Note the accumulation of events by Buffer won't be blocked by a (desirably) synchronous handler.

Comment: As a general observation, it's a bad idea to have a subscriber throw exceptions to a publisher in a push scenario unless you *really want* to blow up the publisher regardless of other subscribers - and there's no general guarantee than a publisher would honour that anyway (it could (even should?) defend itself any carry on publishing) In general, idiomatic Rx is to ensure that subscribers handle their own exceptions. Note that an operator like Do is just as much a Subscriber to its parent as a handler in a Subscribe call.

Comment: With a "Do" in the chain with side-effects, note that the action will run per-subscriber - so you need to be careful how such rx queries are shared; this is one reason why Do's are often avoided. You can easily inadvertently subscribe twice to a source in an operator implementation.